# Japanese number formatting in calcuator app

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to implement Japanese number formatting in my calculator app based on iphone calculator.

I'm running into following problem. After hitting six positions
eg. 85 044 (where one is a space, which is part of formatting after using toLocaleString method), the display goes back to showing only to first two numbers 85. I tried dealing with this problem using split and join methods, but it doesn't work. I think the problem lies with getting rid off a space, which shows after formatting (parseFloat tries to deal with it and fails), but I have run out off ideas how to fix it.

I want all numbers to be displayed using format like this:
00 000
000 000
000 000 000

```
const getValueAsStr = () => {
  const currentDisplayStr = valueEL.textContent;
  return currentDisplayStr.split(" ").join("");
};

const handleNumberClick = (numStr) => {
  const currentDisplayStr = getValueAsStr();
  if (currentDisplayStr === "0") {
    valueEL.textContent = numStr;
  } else {
    valueEL.textContent = parseFloat(
      currentDisplayStr + numStr
    ).toLocaleString();
  }
};

//eventListener for numbers and decimal
for (let i = 0; i < numberElArray.length; i++) {
  const numberEl = numberElArray[i];
  numberEl.addEventListener("click", () => {
    handleNumberClick(i.toString());
  });
}
```

Would greatly appreciate some help on this matter.

Comment: You would have to create a custom function for formatting the value I think.

Comment: I got it working with US number formatting, but for Japanese one the question still stands.